# Can I set up a database just for django testing?

Tags: django, testing

Creating a temp database when running django testing is really time-consuming, so I have a thought to set up a separate database just for django testing. Is it possible? If so, how can i achieve it?

to be more specific: I don't want django to create a new database and do migration and test and destroy every single time I run ./manage.py test. I want it to connect to an existing database(When i already created for testing) and do all the work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`--keepdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---keepdb) option when running the test, so that the database is not destroyed at the end of each run.

```
./manage.py test --keepdb
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but when I do testing on development, I just use SQLite. SQLite is my testing database. When I put it on production, I use PostgreSQL. This is my settings.py when I'm testing on development:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

I used to use PostgreSQL for testing as well (I switched to SQLite because it is quicker to set up).

If I am testing with PostgreSQL, my settings.py would look like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'TESTDB',
        'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

and when I'm not testing, I'd use this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'ProductionDB',
        'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Like I mentioned earlier though, I started using SQLite for testing because it is quicker.

Comment: IMO, you should always use the same type of database in test as in production to avoid any issues that sqlite would let through.

Comment: @limelights True. In that case, I would just use two different DB's of the same type and change the DB in settings.py when I'm testing. Alasdair's solutions seems more efficient.